# dual boot Windows and Linux, SATA Mode

Tags: ubuntu, boot, busybox, sata

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 next to each other, recently I had updated my BIOS version(such a mistake), and couldn't boot any system, so I set up default BIOS version.

So now I can load Windows, but Linux. I have such screen[image]

I read to change SATA Mode to `ahci`, and that works to Linux I can boot it now, but I got blue screen on Windows, and only boot it when change SATA Mode back to `optane without RAID`

What is wrong?

Why does SATA Mode effect so much computer boot?

How can I use my computer as before without going to BIOS all the time?

Comment: Install the Windows AHCI drivers. Windows AHCI instructions - some have found safeboot method better
https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
But if you do a safe boot first to update Windows, then boot to UEFI/BIOS and change to AHCI and finally boot normally, it works
https://superuser.com/questions/1672500/ubuntu-installation-with-intel-rst?noredirect=1#comment2565531_1672500 &

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's probably the easiest to reinstall either Windows or Ubuntu, depending on how much software you have on each.

For Ubuntu, there may be a shortcut: maybe reinstalling grub rather than the whole Linux can fix the issue, since your screenshot mentions issues about the root device. (But if not, backing up the data and then reinstalling ubuntu may be easier).

More specifically, to reinstall grub, you need a Live Ubuntu USB/CD with which you can boot the machine. You can create the live usb either from another working Ubuntu or [from Windows](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview).

First, reboot the machine using the Ubuntu live usb/CD

Then, in the Ubuntu of the Live USB, use the following commands:

(**Be sure to replace `/dev/sda1` with the actual root drive of the broken Ubuntu**)

```
sudo -s
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt   #replace /dev/sda1 with the actual partition number
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo chroot /mnt
mount -a  

grub-install /dev/sda

umount /boot

exit
```

The above allows you to `chroot` into the broken Ubuntu installation and reinstall grub. Hopefully, your new BIOS/machine settings will be recognized correctly in this process.

Then, reboot your machine to see if Ubuntu is fixed:

```
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt
reboot
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with grub. Long story short it's the initramfs that needs to be regenerated with the corresponding driver included (which is often determined by auto detection). Many distros allow you to boot with a "fallback" one which includes as many (relevant) drivers as it could (no auto detection).

Answer (score 0):

AHCI is a legacy hardware access method.  It is emulated over SATA.  SATA is the newer one.  And RAID is often an option in BIOS as well.  Even though its not actually raid, its a way of accessing it.  You generally need to set the protocol at the beginning and leave it. Though sometimes you will find something requiring you to go back to the legacy  versions.

Raid, ASFAIK  really means Intel Rapid Storage Drivers, which are actually fairly good.

I've fallen afoul of this before- changing between one of the 3 settings keeps it from working.  Generally requires a reinstall to change the interface method.  Its not totally clear to me why.

I would agree that if one of these was newly installed go back to the one that worked for the older one and install the new one in that mode.